# Llamar a función de JS con onclick e imprimir resultado en TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, onclick, textarea

Tengo que realizar un programa en HTML que lea dos números enteros y realice distintas acciones dependiendo si son iguales, si el primero es mayor que el segundo, o si el segundo es mayor que el primero.

Esto debo hacerlo con la utilizando el atributo `onclick` y que el resultado sea impreso en una TextArea; sin embargo, el resultado no se imprime o bien, el atributo `onclick` no llama a la función.

He revisado varias veces el código, pero no logro que funcione. Adjunto los códigos para su análisis en busca de errores.

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Practica 2</title>
    <script src="Numeros.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h2>Ingrese dos Números, si el primero es mayo que el segundo, estos serán sumados; Si el segundo es mayor que el primero, se elevaran cada uno al cuadrado y posteriormente se sumaran; Si ambos son iguales, se dividirán</h2>

        Ingrese el primer número:<input type="number" id="uno" placeholder="Escriba un número"><br>
        Ingrese el segundo número:<input type="number" id="dos" placeholder="Escriba otro número"><br><br>

        <input type="button" value="Imprimir Resultados" onclick="Numeros()">
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar"><br><br>

        Resultado:<br><textarea id="r" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Código JS:

```
function Numeros(){
    n1=document.getElementById("uno").value;
    n2=document.getElementById("dos").value;
    else if (n1>n2) {
        r=n1+n2;
    }
    else if(n2>n1){
        n1c=n1*n1;
        n2c=n2*n2;
        r=n1c+n2c;
    }
    else{
        r=n1/n2;
    }
    document.getElementById("r").value;
}
```

Comment: Consejo: en JS regularmente los nombres de las funciones se escriben en [camelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) -también conocido como `lowerCamelCase`. La nomenclatura `UpperCamelCase` usualmente es utilizada para nombrar Clases.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos errores en tu código de JS:

1. En la 4ta línea, estás utilizando `else` que no corresponde a ningún `if`. Elimínalo.
2. Para colocar el valor que calculaste en el `textarea` con `id="r"` puedes utilizar:

   ```
   document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = r;
   ```

Comment: Muchas grácias, ya funciona el código, sin embargo, hay un probema, se supone que cuando el primer número es mayor al segundo, estos deben sumarse. Sin embargo, en lugar de sumarse de forma matemática, se suman como si fuesen String y solo los muestra juntos, Osea:

si los numeros son 5 y 3
En lugar de mostrar _8_
Este muestra _53_

Sabes por que podría ser esto?

Comment: El tipo por defecto al obtener el valor de un elemento es `String`. Antes de hacer los cálculos matemáticos, puedes hacer `n1 =parseInt(n1)` y lo respectivo para `n2`. Debes tener cuidado, porque si el usuario introduce una letra, esta función lanzará un error.